# Non repeating content change for wordpress using add_filter

Tags: wordpress, preg-replace

I want to put a pdf icon in for pdf links automatically in wordpress

```
function my_function($content) {
    $search = '^.pdf">^';
    $replace='.pdf"><img src="domain.com/pdf-icon.jpg" width="64" height="64" alt="pdf download"/>';
    return preg_replace($search,$replace,$content);
}
add_filter('content_save_pre','my_function');
```

Works, but if the post is edited again another image gets added.
How do I change it to not replace where the search for `.pdf` has the img tag already straight after it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd not use database content insertion at all in favor of a CSS solution:

```
a[href $='.pdf'] { 
   padding-right: 64px;
   background: transparent url(domain.com/pdf-icon.jpg) no-repeat center right;
}
```

Comment: D'oh why didn't I think of that - brilliant, thank you so much!